# Why is chromium more brittle than iron at room temperature?

Tags: material-science, metals

Why is chromium more [brittle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brittleness) than iron?  I understand that both of them are BCC at room temperature.  Is it to do with the grain size? Why is it different between the two metals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The brittleness is [caused](http://lib.dr.iastate.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4183&context=rtd) primarily by interstitial impurities. That's the case of chromium as well as all Group VI A metals. For chromium, the nitrogen atoms are the main impurities.